# HTML5 D&D loosing dataTransfer data, please advise

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I made a small demo but the data attached via dataTransfer is lost.
Here is my code example:

```
var element = document.getElementById('draggable');
element.addEventListener('dragstart', function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    evt.dataTransfer.setData('test', 'some_dummy_data');
} );

var zone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
zone.addEventListener('dragenter', function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation(); evt.preventDefault();
    console.log( '>>>', evt.dataTransfer.getData( 'test' ) );
} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U24sC/33/

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Works with firefox and chrome but not in safari :(

Answer (score 0):

"Note: For security purposes, the getData method can be called only from within the ondrop event handler."

Reference: [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/DragAndDrop.html)